# Terra.js (wasm.ContractQuery) has error status code 500

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with JavaScript error in Terra.js.
Can any one suggest me how to get through it.
Here is my code:

```
const run = async () => {
  let pairData = {
    pair: {
      asset_infos: [
        {
          token: {
            contract_addr: "terra1s5eczhe0h0jutf46re52x5z4r03c8hupacxmdr",
          },
        },
        {
          native_token: {
            denom: "uusd",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  const pair = await terra.wasm.contractQuery(
    "terra1s5eczhe0h0jutf46re52x5z4r03c8hupacxmdr",
    Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(pairData)).toString("base64")
  );

  console.log(pair);
};

run();
```

With this code, this error is occurred.
Error: Request failed with status code 500

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to base64, provide the message as JSON and the sdk will automatically convert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, `@terra-money/terra.js` package version is > "^2.0".
And building the query json got easy.

You just need to insert ordinary JSON object as the parameter.

So, in your case, you just need to insert `pairData`, no need any `Buffer` or `JSON.stringify` conversions.